# Loading external dependencies in Zeppelin on Spark in Yarn-Client mode on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, apache-zeppelin

Dear community! Before I describe the problem, here's a short description of the software in use (where the latter two are running in a small cluster of three nodes, each of them using **Ubuntu 14.04**):

- **Zeppelin 0.6.1**
- **Spark 2.0.0** along with **Scala 2.11.8**
- **Hadoop 2.7.3**

The situation is as follows: In order to use the **TwitterUtils** class in a Spark Streaming application written in a Zeppelin note, I need to include **org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._** from Maven (**org.apache.bahir:spark-streaming-twitter_2.11:2.0.0-preview**). What I learned so far is that there are a couple of options to make external dependencies available in Zeppelin:

- Export the **SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS** variable in **conf/zeppelin-env.sh** and set **--jars** (in my case **--jars hdfs://admdsmaster:54310/global/jars/spark-streaming-twitter_2.11-2.0.0-preview.jar** (path pointing to local file system was tested as well)).
- Export **SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS** and set **--packages** (in my case **--packages org.apache.bahir:spark-streaming-twitter_2.11:2.0.0-preview**).
- Set **spark.jars** or **spark.jars.packages** in **conf/spark-defaults.conf** with the values mentioned above.
- Use the **%dep** interpreter in Zeppelin itself like so: **z.load("org.apache.bahir:spark-streaming-twitter_2.11:2.0.0-preview")**. This is deprecated, though.
- Use **sc.addJar()** in the Zeppelin note to manually add a .jar file.

After having tried all of the above -- and almost arbitrary combinations and variations thereof -- the problem is that I still can't import the **TwitterUtils** class from within a Zeppelin note:

[Class import failing in Zeppelin note.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oETWc.png)

What can be seen from the picture as well is the output of **sc.listJars()** which shows that the .jar file was actually included. Nonetheless, the class import fails.

My first thought was that the problem occurs because Spark is running in yarn-client mode, so I started the Spark shell in yarn-client mode as well and tried to import the **TwitterUtils** class from there -- which worked:

[Class import working from Spark shell.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6pBr.png)

In order to find out what's going on, I searched the log files of Zeppelin, Spark and YARN, but couldn't find any error messages to point me to the cause of the problem.

**Long story short**: Although the jar file was included in Zeppelin (as proven by **sc.listJars()**) and although the class import works from the spark-shell in yarn-client mode, I just can't get the import to work from within my Zeppelin note.

**Long story even shorter**: I'd really appreciate your ideas on how to solve this problem!

Thanks in advance for your time and effort.

P.S.: I'm sorry for the fact that I could not upload the images to this post directly -- it says that I need at least 10 reputation points which I do not have as this is my first ever post here.

Comment: Did you try adding them from the interpreter tab ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the dependency from the interpreter tab as proposed by @eliasah actually did the trick -- thank you very much!

For the fellows out there who might be running into the same problem, I'm going to describe the solution very shortly and add a picture of how a call to **sc.listJars()** should actually look like (compared to the picture in the original question).

Head over to Zeppelin's interpreter tab and scroll down or search for the **spark** interpreter, then hit **edit**. At the very bottom of the available settings there is a **Dependencies** section. Add your dependency here (by specifying the Maven coordinates, for example, in my case **org.apache.bahir:spark-streaming-twitter_2.11:2.0.0-preview**) and save the settings. After restarting your interpreter, the dependency should be available.

Here's what a call to **sc.listJars()** looked like in my case after having executed the steps described above:

[image: Call to sc.listJars().]

If you compare this picture to the first one in the original question, you'll notice that the list now contains a lot more entries. I'm still wondering, though, why the class import did not work when only the .jar file containing it was present. Anyway, problem solved thanks to @eliasah -- thanks again, you deserve a cookie! -- and I hope that this short description will help others as well.